# Search substring in a NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am using a `NSPopupbutton`. I get the title of the selected item and put it in a `NSString`

```
NSString *selected = [mypopup titleOfSelectedItem];
```

at next i have a `NSArray` the content is loaded from an file.

Now i do a search like this:

```
for (NSString *line in mystringarray){
    NSRange result = [line rangeOfString:selected];
    if (result.location != NSNotFound){
        NSLog(@"%@",not found);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@",line);
    }
}
```

but this would not work. If i am changing the selected to @"myword" it works.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, what's the value of `selected` just before using it?

Comment: If i am put this into the code:
NSLog(@"%@",selected);
It show me in the console output the String of mypopupbutton.
The Breakpoint shows my:
selected=(_NSCFString *)@"mytext\r"

Comment: I guess you might wanna change you if condition (or the NSLog() output: You do `result.location != NSNotFound` then log `not found`, but you should prove if the location **is** NSNotFound, then it is not found. Change it to `result.location == NSNotFound`

Comment: Changed but has no effect. Is it a problem with the endings \r of selected.

Comment: So you just want to find the string of title of the selected item within the file content? But you've separated the lines of text into an array?

Comment: I find out that the selected item is 1 count higher as the @"my text".
long i=selected.length;
    NSLog(@"%ld",i);
long i=selected.length;
    NSLog(@"%ld",i);

Comment: Problem solved, i use this

NSString *searchfor=[selected substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,selected.length-1)];